# Issue with drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu and i am trying to implement a drop down menu on hover, It doesn't seem to appear correct,any help would be appreciated. Why is the drop down appearing in different position ?

```
 <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a> 
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li></ul>
  </li> |
                <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li> |
                <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li> |
                <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li> |
                <li><a href="contact.html">Reach Us</a></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>

.menu{
float:left;
color: #555555;
margin-top: 25px;

}
.menu ul {} 
.menu  li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin:6px 20px;
}
.menu  li a{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 14px;    
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    padding: 5px;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
} 

.menu  li.active a{
    color: #52ABDF;
    background: white;
}
.menu  li a:hover{
    color: #ooo;
    background: #52ABDF;
    padding: 5px;
}

 .menu li ul{
        display: none;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover ul{
        display: block;
      margin-left:0px;
    }
.menu li ul li { 
    float: none; 
    display: inline; 
}
.menu li ul li a { 
    position: relative; 
    border-left: 1px solid black; 
    border-right: 1px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    background: #333; 
    color: #ooo; 
}
.menuli ul li a:hover { 
    background: #066; 
    color: #000; 
}
```

Here is the code pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EtmAB

Comment: Seem because you give your drop down menu a class="menu", which has the margin-top: 25px; property

Comment: I have removed the margin but still it appears to be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a tip,

> **you should never use '|' symbol to seperate the `<li>`s, because it
>   makes the html meaningless. The `<ul>` tag is expected to have only
>   `<li>` tags as its children.. You could use the border-right property instead. and use**

```
ul li:last-of-type(){
  border: 0;
}
```

> **to eliminate the border on the last `<li>`**

Use this css and yours would work:

```
.menu,
.menu li ul{
    float:left;
    color: #555555;
    margin-top: 0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu{
  margin-top: 25px;
}
.menu ul:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.menu  li{
    float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.menu  li a{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-size: 14px;    
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 20px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
} 

.menu  li.active a{
    color: #52ABDF;
    background: white;
}
.menu  li a:hover{
    color: #ooo;
    background: #52ABDF;
}

.menu li ul{
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: #bbb;
}
.menu li ul li { 
    display: inline ; 
}
.menu li ul li a { 
    position: relative; 
    border-left: 1px solid black; 
    border-right: 1px solid black; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
    background: #333; 
    color: #ooo; 
}
.menuli ul li a:hover { 
    background: #066; 
    color: #000; 
}
```

If you want to really learn how to make a better styled dropdown menu, use this tutorial:
http://andornagy.com/css-dropdown-menu/

it is pretty easy and understandable too, and not bad looking...

Comment: Thank you for the help, Here is what I have tried.  Could you help me out with hover issue in about tab ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EtmAB

Comment: Sorry, its wierd posting a code in comment. So, just go to the 'fourth last' rule (.menu li ul) in the above code. include that too.

Comment: Oh, I see you've added it. its just a problem of ';' after the 'margin: 0px' in the same rule that you've shown on codepen. Now it sholud be solved... :)

Comment: Thank you so much, Had been struggling since 5 hours.